# Find IR codes for a LIRC remote

Tags: pi-3, kodi, remote, openelec, lirc

I'm trying to find IR codes for my old Panasonic Viera TV (model: `tx26le7pa`) and load them into LIRC.

irrecord, you say? That would be awesome if only the remote wasn't broken (in half).

There is nothing in the LIRC remote database nor pretty much anywhere on the internet. Many wesbites have tons of Panasonic remote codes, but none support my TV model.

I did however find something [here](ftp://ftp.panasonic.com/pub/panasonic/Drivers/Monitors/Discrete-remote-control-codesProntoCCFformat.pdf) from Panasonic, but again, not my exact TV model. Although ftp.panasonic.com is a huge repository of files, drivers manuals and whatnot so something could be there, but I just don't have the time to go through all of it.

**My question:**

**Is there any way of getting the codes without buying a new remote?** Like the universal remote devices do it? Can I somehow run through all possible codes and save ones that trigger an action that I need (I only really need Power on/Standby code and TV/AV switcher code). Or are there any other methods of abtaining the codes I need?

Comment: Borrow a universal remote replacemnt from a friend and once you get it working with your tv record the codes with lirc.

Comment: Although this is a good idea, I don't think I know anyone that has a universal remote. And even if they did, I probably didn't notice. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a thrift store, salvation army, or dollar store near you - they are good sources to pick up not only remote controls but power supplies (phone chargers) as well.

Comment: Worst comes to worst "universal remotes" tend to be pretty cheap because of the economics of scale and the fact that anyone will make them.  I'm sure I've noticed them in, e.g., hardware stores and pharmacies (that may be a regional thing here because of certain major chains, but for sure you will find them in department or of course, electronics stores) for $10-15 USD.   The gamble is it won't work, in which case buy it somewhere that will take it back for that reason within 7 days (which suddenly gives me a **sneaky idea** about who you could "borrow" one from).

Comment: @goldilocks There are a bunch of electronic and thrift stores in my city. I'll just get an universal remote, record it in irrecord and return it. Hahah..

Comment: Maybe this site might help:  [Remote codes](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/panasonic/)

Comment: @Janekmuric I would hang on to the remote they can be a great way to control a circuit, or trigger an action.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I already have tons of unused remotes in my house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an universal remote and recorded it with irrecord. Here is the config:

```
# Please make this file available to others
# by sending it to <lirc@bartelmus.de>
#
# this config file was automatically generated
# using lirc-0.9.1-git(default) on Tue Aug 30 18:19:24 2016
#
# contributed by 
#
# brand:                       /storage/.config/tv.conf
# model no. of remote control: 
# devices being controlled by this remote:
#

begin remote

  name  mytv
  bits           24
  flags SPACE_ENC
  eps            30
  aeps          100

  header       3453  1721
  one           420  1305
  zero          420   441
  ptrail        422
  pre_data_bits   24
  pre_data       0x400401
  gap          73341
  toggle_bit_mask 0x0

      begin codes
          KEY_POWER                0x00BCBD
          KEY_OK                   0x009293
          KEY_INFO                 0x009C9D
          KEY_UP                   0x005253
          KEY_DOWN                 0x00D2D3
          KEY_LEFT                 0x007273
          KEY_RIGHT                0x00F2F3
          KEY_MENU                 0x004A4B
          KEY_EXIT                 0x00CBCA
          KEY_VOLUMEUP             0x000405
          KEY_VOLUMEDOWN           0x008485
          KEY_MUTE                 0x004C4D
          KEY_CHANNELUP            0x002C2D
          KEY_CHANNELDOWN          0x00ACAD
          KEY_RED                  0x000E0F
          KEY_GREEN                0x008E8F
          KEY_YELLOW               0x004E4F
          KEY_BLUE                 0x00CECF
          KEY_1                    0x000809
          KEY_2                    0x008889
          KEY_3                    0x004849
          KEY_4                    0x00C8C9
          KEY_5                    0x002829
          KEY_6                    0x00A8A9
          KEY_7                    0x006869
          KEY_8                    0x00E8E9
          KEY_9                    0x001819
          KEY_0                    0x009899
          KEY_CONFIG               0x00A0A1
          KEY_BACK                 0x00ECED
          KEY_AUDIO                0x00CCCD
          KEY_TEXT                 0x80C041
          KEY_T                    0x8040C1
      end codes

end remote
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  Remember to put everything back in the box carefully. ;)

Comment: @goldilocks The store is just down the street.